# Would quick draw and combat reflexes allow you to make attacks of opportunity with sheathed weapons?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, opportunity-attack

If you have quick draw and combat reflexes, could you threaten squares around you with sheathed weapons?

Quick draw allows you to pull out a weapon as a free action. Combat reflexes allows you to make AOO's when flatfooted during a surprise round. Is it unreasonable to think that together they would allow you to look innocent but catch them off guard with your weapon?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### By the rules, no

Free actions are still actions, and as such, can only be taken during your turn unless specifically stated (such as with [speaking](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat/#TOC-Free-Actions)).

I personally think that it's a reasonable houserule to allow it, however. I cannot see it breaking any mechanics in the 1pp Pathfinder game.